# ReadProcessMemory _out_ bytesread

Tags: c++, windows, readprocessmemory

The program uses `ReadProcessMemory` to scan through chunks of memory for a certain value. Unfortunately when I call `ReadProcessMemory` I get error 299.

```
void update_memblock(MEMBLOCK *mb)
{
    //variables
    static unsigned char tempbuf[128*1024];
    size_t bytes_left;
    size_t total_read;
    size_t bytes_to_read;
    size_t  bytes_read;
    size_t sizeMem;
    size_t MemoryBase;

    bytes_left = mb->size;
    total_read = 0;

    while (bytes_left)
    {

        bytes_to_read = (bytes_left > sizeof(tempbuf)) ? sizeof(tempbuf) :  bytes_left;
        ReadProcessMemory(mb->hProc ,mb->addr + total_read,mb->buffer, bytes_to_read, (SIZE_T*)&bytes_read);
        if (bytes_read != bytes_to_read)break;
        memcpy(mb->buffer + total_read, tempbuf,bytes_read);

        bytes_left -= bytes_read;
        total_read += bytes_read;
    }
    mb->size = total_read;
}
```

Comment: "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed." -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You need to use [VirtualProtect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx) to ensure that all the memory is writable.

Comment: @xboi209: he's reading, not writing.  (Most likely he's running into a part of the address space that isn't allocated.)

Comment: Why are you reading the data into `tempbuf` and copying it to `mb->buffer` rather than just reading it directly into `mb->buffer` ?

Comment: My bad, I meant readable*

Comment: @xboi209 i virtual query the info in another method to check if its readable

Comment: @HarryJohnston in the function that calls this It checks to make sure the memory is committed before calling update_memblock / function posted

Comment: Perhaps it stops when it hits the boundary between consecutive allocations.  (The documentation doesn't say anything about that, but it seems a reasonable thing for it to do.)  What is `bytes_read` after you receive the error?  If you carry on and issue another read from the new address, does that read work?  If not, what error do you get?

Comment: do you need any clarification or have any criticism or my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Erorr Code 299 (0x12B) ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY
"Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed"

You're receiving this error because you're trying to read memory from a page that isn't "allocated".

You want to use [VirtualQueryEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx) on each page of memory which yields a [MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, which contains 2 variables of note:

State: can be MEM_COMMIT, MEM_FREE or MEM_RESERVE
Protect: can be any of the [Memory Protection Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx)

You want to loop through all the pages of memory, call VirtualQueryEx() on them and skip any pages that are bad.  I like to skip all pages/regions in which state != MEM_COMMIT and Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS

Here is a psuedo code example:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi = { 0 };

while (LoopingThroughTheMemories.bat)
{
    if (!VirtualQueryEx(hProc, currentMemoryAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) continue
    if (mbi.State != MEM_COMMIT || mbi.Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS) continue;

    //good mem region, do ReadProcessMemory() stuffs
}
```